# Auto Insert date into Notepad

Tags: windows-10, date-time, notepad

I am using Notepad - the standard plain old plain old in Windows 10 Home 64.

I had been typing up some notes and one of my sentences was not correct - I accidentally pasted some text over what I was typing in:
So I was typing this: DISPLAY and CREATE and EDIT 
Some large paragraph of text that I had copied previously got inserted over top of my writing (basically a snippet of just text). I had my text hilited (I think) .
I went to Ctrl-Z to undo and as I was doing that somehow my big fingers hit more than one key and I ended up with the CURRENT date and time stamp inserted.

/ 5:43 AM 3/3/2019IT

So I have tried to identify what I had done in order to accomplish that .. and I am unable to determine how in the world I managed to get the current date and time inserted into notepad!

Any idea how this is accomplished?

I do not want alternate suggestions of using Notepad++ or this or that - I want to know how it is possible to do this in the standard Notepad - because somehow I managed to do it by accident.

Comment: [5 Things You Didn’t Know You Could Do with Windows Notepad](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/5-groovy-things-about-notepad-exe/), [Inserting Date Time by pressing F5 like in notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46724571/995714), [Windows Notepad: Insert Time and Date into Text or Log File](https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/909/windows-notepad-insert-time-and-date-into-text-or-log-file/)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want to insert the date and time into Notepad, press <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: or Edit>Time/Date

Comment: @Moab - never occurred to me to check that - as notepad had been so bland for years - I never checked to see if there were any enhancements! Thx..

Comment: Windows 7 also had it.

Comment: I believe it has been a default feature since before Windows XP. At that time, that function already existed.

Comment: @StixO: recent enhancement? LOL, this goes back to Windows 3.11 and earlier! https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk997.png

Comment: @Ismael: [It's a little older than that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOyxb.png)

Comment: @Matteo: [Boom!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8n9n.png)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: argh I've been over-archeologized. My only excuse for that is that Windows 1 & co. was around when I wasn't even born. 

Comment: @MatteoItalia Awkward 

Comment: How does one hit F5 while reaching for Ctrl+Z?

Comment: @Kevin Z is not always on the bottom row of the keyboard. French keyboards have it as the second key on the top row (which is AZERTY rather than QWERTY). German keyboard have it as the 6th key on the top row (QWERTZ). In either case, on some keyboards (e.g. laptop keyboards) where function keys are obtained with Fn + regular number key, it's not too much of a stretch to go from Ctrl-Z to Fn-5 (though not quite obvious either)

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the F5 method (which wrt your last paragraph I understand exactly answers your question), you can also use the [auto-timestamp feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/260563/how-to-use-notepad-to-create-a-log-file) by starting the file with .LOG

This will ensure the timestamp is added each time you reopen and edit the file.

Comment: Last update 17 April 2018 and describes OS features ("Programs -> Accessories") that were last part of a Windows product almost 20 years ago. Nice!

Comment: BTW this Notepad feature still works. Wow, I can imagine that being annoying if your arbitrary file happens to start with the line `.LOG` :D